# Create table with different linux user in Hive is giving exception

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive

I have existing Hadoop setup with Hive, a new user on Linux node is unable to create the table giving below exception:

```
(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied: user=
 access=WRITE, inode="/bigdata/hivetmp/user/hive/warehouse/gpeh.db":hadoop1:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
```

However, with same user I am able to create the database.
I have provided necessary access to the user on required folders.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a permission issue.
If you see at the HDFS level 
**inode="/bigdata/hivetmp/user/hive/warehouse/gpeh.db" :hadoop1:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x at**

That means the new user doesnt have write permission at the database.
You can just change it to give the new user write permission and try again.